# adding components to or upgrading custom jquery ui installs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[jQuery UI's Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) is pretty neat. It lets you download just the components of jQuery UI that you need instead of downloading the whole thing. Unfortunately, there's one small problem with that.

What if you're doing further development on your site and you want to make use of a jQuery UI component that your site doesn't currently use? You could download jQuery UI again but if you don't know what components you're currently using... do you just download the whole thing even if you're only going to be using 2-3 components?

And what if you want to upgrade your jQuery UI install but don't know what components you're currently using?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the point of which Components, you can download the whole pack, but include on the files you use in your project.

ex. Only 'jquery.ui.accordion.min' and 'jquery.ui.datepicker.min'

and for later upgrades, you can use the JQuery/JQuery-UI Online CDN along with your custom 'js' files that are referenced after the original Online Links. This way, you will have the latest versions and keep your custom code unchanged.

This will save you some hassle.